# D: What about streams?

Tags: stream, d

D seems like a language with very high potential and I'm highly interested in what the future holds for it. I'm curious though, is there any discussion about including streams in D? The C++ streams have been of great help to me in the past and they seem a lot cleaner than using functions like `printf`/`writefln` or whatever.

Comment: What functionality do you feel is missing, exactly?

Comment: The way you read from (write to) the console, files, etc. isn't that big of deal. However, in C++ I've found it useful however to pass streams as function parameters (either `std::ostream&` or `std::istream&`), not to mention overloading the `<<` and `>>` operators in my custom classes which can sometimes be very useful, especially when writing classes that abstract math concepts, like fractions or complex numbers. Basically, streams are a lot more versatile and allow for more generic programming.

Comment: I agree. Using streams is much more WYSIWYG than the old printf style. Its really the difference between int i = Add(4,3) and int i = 4+3. Same functionality, but hardly the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's currently talk of deprecating the current std.stream design and rewriting it.  Andrei Alexandrescu [posted the interfaces for a proposed new design](http://erdani.com/d/phobos/std_stream2.html) based on D2's ranges awhile back.  Unfortunately the community is short on manpower and trying to get a whole bunch of other library support working, like networking, parallelism, database APIs, containers, etc.  Streams are on the agenda, but not on the front burner.

Answer (score 1):

Well the current streaming interface is in http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_stream.html

But I think it will be refactored sometime.

Answer (score 1):

D has a standard way to pass around thing like a file, a open network connection and stdout. (See other answers) It also has a standard way to convert a struct/object to a string (toString, unless it's been changed). Personally, that gets you all of the parts of C++ streams that I like. I would be opposed to adding the operator overloading stuff as it makes thing like separation of data and format nearly impossible.